# Is it possible to customize “X would like to use your current location” on the iPhone?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is it possible to style the location alert box: "(app name) would like to use your current location” on the iPhone?

Comment: Yep.  I guess he has (or is) a good publicist :-)

Comment: Yea you can say that again... :) it's a sad reality that those famous questions were really just because they were the first questions of a really popular problem when iOS was new. Harder these days to get some of those popular badges.

Comment: Sadly, my question that is closest to having enough views for that badge just boils down to a typo in my code.

Comment: Early adopters asking good questions should be rewarded because they add values to the site when it needed it the most.

Comment: I agree.  Not complaining about your gold badges at all. 10K views each question means they helped a lot of people.  I just hope I don't end up getting a gold badge over what turned out to be a typo.

Comment: Hey Boon, not at all, great acheivment and the fruits of many hours helping others. I'm doing my best to help out here as much I can, aspiring to get a gold soon...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only tell user the reason for using his location by setting [purpose](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/purpose) property of `CLLocationManager`.

**EDIT:**
The `purpose` property is deprecated in iOS 6. But there is a replacement. For iOS 6 and above you should add `NSLocationUsageDescription` key to your Info.plist file. If your app targets iOS versions lower than 6.0, you might want to do both.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is an operating system level feature designed to protect privacy.

If it could be customized, someone would change it to something like "Do you like kittens?" and be able to gain access to location information of people that like kittens.

Answer (score 1):

No this is a system feature, but you can provide a descriptif text for why you want to use the users location, this text is added to the dialog box. The property you need to use for this is called `purpose` and is a property on the `CLLocationManager` class.

Please check out this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125